# Multiple email templates using a single workflow

Tags: visualforce, workflow

can i send different email templates to a user using a single workflow rule.
for example i have 3 email templates:
1.for Application started
2.for Application Completed
3.for Application accepted.
i have one field application status.
and i have one workflow rule.on the basis of the value of application status field,i want to choose among the available email templates and send it to user.
Can i implement this functionality using a single workflow rule or do i need to create multiple workflows for this?

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create multiple WF rules since the logic for each email being sent will be different.